# Dapps development in ccp ethereum(Aleth zero)

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I am starting in Dapps development for Ethereum , I'm trying  to install AlethZero i'm using windows 7 but i have an error when i try to execute it: MSVCR120.dll is missing 
is there any solution for this??
what should i do ??

Answer (score 0):

AlethZero is deprecated for more than a year now and the C++ Ethereum project dead. You should get [Go-Ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum) or [Parity](https://github.com/ethcore/parity):

[image: Parity Screenshot]

See also [Writing Dapps for Parity](https://github.com/ethcore/parity/wiki/Writing-Dapps-for-Parity).